# iOS Why won't my app load data into the tableview until it's restarted?

Tags: ios, uitableview, magicalrecord

In my nooby quest to learn how to properly load data into a grouped table view from Core Data, I built a very simple little two-view app. I use MagicalRecord as my interface with CD.

**The current problem is that, while input data is being saved to my store as expected, the table view isn't refreshed upon saving to display the new data. However, if I stop the app in the simulator, then restart from Xcode, the new data is displayed in the tableview.**

I'm using NotificationCenter rather than delegation for the communiation. Here is the code from my initial View Controller (containing and delegate to the tableview), followed by the code from the AddViewController, used to add data. Can someone with MagicalRecord experience please shine a light on me? Thanks!

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  MRGroupingTest
//
//  Created by Tim Jones on 1/9/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 TDJ. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ListActivity.h"

@interface ViewController ()

{
    NSFetchedResultsController *frc;
}


@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self refreshData];
    frc = [ListActivity MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:@"category" withPredicate:nil sortedBy:@"name" ascending:YES];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificationNewActivityAdded:) name:@"newActivityAdded" object:nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void) notificationNewActivityAdded:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}



#pragma mark Table View data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[frc sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[frc sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    int rows = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    return rows;

}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[frc sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo name];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    if ([frc sections] > 0)
    {
        ListActivity *activity = [frc objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text = activity.name;

    }

    return cell;

}

-(void) refreshData
{

    frc = [ListActivity MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:@"category" withPredicate:nil sortedBy:@"name" ascending:YES];

    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}


#pragma mark Table View delegate

@end
```

And here's the code from AddViewController:

```
//
//  AddViewController.m
//  MRGroupingTest
//
//  Created by Tim Jones on 1/9/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 TDJ. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AddViewController.h"

@interface AddViewController ()

@end

@implementation AddViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)saveAction:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];

    ListActivity * thisActivity = [ListActivity MR_createInContext:localContext];
    thisActivity.name =  self.activityField.text;
    thisActivity.category = self.categoryField.text;
    [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
    //Inform app
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"newActivityAdded" object:localContext];
    //dismiss view
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


}

- (IBAction)cancelAction:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"newActivityAdded" object:localContext];
    //dismiss view
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reload your TableView data, i.e. Call the `reloadData` function

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm obviously missing something critical here. Where should I add this call, specifically?

Comment: Well, he has the reloadData call, in refreshData.  But odds are there's a nil pointer somewhere, or a bogus second copy of an object, so reloadData isn't being called on the real TableView.

Comment: @HotLicks--your comment aroused a concern that there could be a conflict between the local variable "tableView" in the boilerplate data source code I'm using, and the property called "tableView" on my ViewController. So I went back and changed it, along with another couple of changes reflecting the suggestion of the first commenter. See edit for revised ViewController code. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @TimJones - It sounds like you've tied yourself in a knot.  You need to go back and carefully think it through, and do some debugging (see whether you ever execute reloadData, and whether the pointer to the TableView is good when you do).

Comment: Wouldn't be the first time I've been in a knot. :) I'll do as you suggest and report back. Thanks!

Comment: @HotLicks--OK, a more knowledgable friend helped me walk through the code this morning, and although he too found the behavior baffling, we finally discovered a couple of redundancies and, unsettlingly, that the addObserver line in viewDidLoad was commented out, even though it's not in the code I originally posted. Can't explain it, although I'm clearly the only suspect. In any case, it now works, so I'm going to mark this question resolved. Some different questions about the MagicalRecord sorting and grouping methods remain, but I'll ask them separately. Many thanks to you guys!